# How to map a key shortcut to a bookmark?

Tags: firefox, vimperator, pentadactyl

I'm using `pentadactyl` in my Firefox as a keyboard enthusiast.

Now I'm thinking of using key shortcut to easily access one of my bookmarks, which actually contains a javascript to run (so apparently it is not working with <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>t</kbd> to open a keyworded bookmark)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for quickmarks. As the help describes:

> A QuickMark is simply a URL assigned to a letter
>       or digit. They can therefore be saved or opened with only three key
>       presses each. QuickMarks are persistent across browser sessions.

Thus `:qmark a aol.com` defines the shortcut to the letter `a`. In order to go to the quickmark, you'd type `goa`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a [QuickMark](http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/marks.xhtml)? I'd give you a specific syntax, but I am afraid to give you the wrong directions.